# map update in cassandra with cql3

Tags: collections, cassandra, cql

i have a CF in cassandra that have a coulmn type map

this CF is as below:

```
CREATE TABLE word_cat ( 
   word text, 
   doc_occurrence map <text, int >,
   total_occurrence map <text, int >,   
   PRIMARY KEY (word)
);
```

i want to update doc_occurrence so that value of a key pluse with a new number.i want to do this in one query.

i think in can done in a query like this:

```
UPDATE word_cat SET doc_occurrence ['key']=doc_occurrence ['key']+5 WHERE word='name';
```

but it could not work, can any body help?

Answer (score 0):

Better to explain with example, so I am considering only your schema.

**Now here i am inserting some data, followed by the output**

```
cqlsh:ks1> update word_cat set
           ...  doc_occurrence=
           ...  {'cassandra' : 1}
           ...  where word ='name';
cqlsh:ks1> SELECT * FROM word_cat ;

 word | doc_occurrence | total_occurrence
------+----------------+------------------
 name | {cassandra: 1} |             null
```

**Now if you want to overwrite an already existing key (cassandra with value 5) in your map, so here you go**

```
cqlsh:ks1> update word_cat set
           ...  doc_occurrence=
           ...  {'cassandra' : 5}
           ...  where word ='name';

cqlsh:ks1> SELECT * FROM word_cat ;

 word | doc_occurrence | total_occurrence
------+----------------+------------------
 name | {cassandra: 5} |             null
```

**Update:**

The functionality you are referring in your comment is including a counter value in a map. But unfortunately counters are not allowed inside a collection, rather i will say it is not supported yet.
May be you can have a separate counter column family to handle those things.

Comment: no, i want to plus value of existing key with new value.
in this example the value of cassandra become 1+5=6
{cassandra:6}